# for a compact manifold $M$, is the dual space of $H^1(M)$ equal to $H^{-1}(M)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Is it true that
$$(H^1(M))^* = H^{-1}(M)?$$

is there some intuitive explanation why? Or some reference? Thanks

Here $H^1$ is the usual Sobolev space of $u \in L^2(M)$ with $\nabla u \in L^2(M)$.

Comment: How do you define $H^{-1}(M)$? Typically, one has $(H_0^1(M))* = H^{-1}(M)$.

Comment: @gerw Well if $M$ were a bounded domain it is defined as a space of distributions, presumably we can do something similar for $M$ compact manifold. I take it your definition of compact manifold does not necessarily imply $\partial M = 0$ like I intended, by your comment?

Answer (score 0):

No, we only define the dual of $(H_0^1(M))$ is $H^{-1}(M)$, but not $H^1(M)$. Although the dual of $H^1(M)$ does exist, and it is smaller then $H^{-1}(M)$.

If you want an intuitive explanation, I recommend you to read the definition by Fourior transform then you will see the dual of $H^s$ is $H^{-s}$, not by definition but by computation.

Comment: But $M$ is compact, isn't that $H^1_0(M)= H^1(M)$?

Comment: No, how about just a constant function over $M$?

Comment: A constant function is of compact support?

Comment: In my understanding, and his definition, $H^1(M)$ contains all $W^{1,2}$ function on compact manifold $M$, but not all $W^{1,2}$ function with compact support in $M$.

Comment: But $M$ is compact, all functions have compact support.

Comment: Sorry, i confused. A function is defined on a compact set $M$ does not equivalent to a function has compact support inside $M$... Or is there something simple i missed? So you are saying if $M$ is compact then $H_0^1(M)=H^1(M)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But of course I was thinking of compact manifold WITHOUT boundary.

Comment: Well, sorry then. In that case you are right. I just worry about what if $M$ is bounded.